# Checking, if all enum values were processed

Tags: c#, security, unit-testing, enums, static-analysis

Suppose, that there's a piece of code:

```
enum Directions
{
    North,
    South,
    East,
    West
}

// (...)

switch (dir)
{
    case North : // Do sth
    case South : // Do sth
    case East : // Do sth
    case West : // Do sth
}
```

Notice especially the lack of `default:` directive. Now suppose, that later someone added four more values to that enum: `NorthEast`, `NorthWest`, `SouthEast`, `SouthWest`. In such case it is likely, that the quoted code will effect in undefined behavior, because there is no security measure to handle possible extensions to Directions enumeration type.

I've got some questions regarding this matter.

1. Shall a programmer implement a security measure here, eg:

   ```
   default: throw new InvalidArgumentException("Unsupported enum value!");
   ```
2. Should this matter be tested in unit testing?

   ```
   // Naïve implementation, for example purposes only
   [ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidArgumentException))]
   [Test]
   void SomeTestMethod()
   {
       SomeFunction((Direction)-1);
   }
   ```

   If so, how would you automate such kind of test (eg. find ordinal value different from all other values in this enum, take into consideration enum backing type etc.)?
3. Should this matter be verified during static code analysis? Which tool can provide such informations? I've written simple Proof-of-concept in VS 2012 Pro, run code analysis, but IDE reported, that 'No code analysis issues were detected'.

   The code:

   ```
   namespace ManagedConsoleSketchbook
   {
       class Program
       {
           enum MyEnum
           {
               One,
               Two,
               Three
           }

           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               MyEnum e = MyEnum.One;

               switch (e)
               {
                   case MyEnum.One:
                       break;
                   case MyEnum.Two:
                       break;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Is there a generic approach to this general problem? Eg. maybe I can write sophisticated test method in C# using reflection, but in C++ it's a lot harder to nail down such *potential* code integrity breach than in C# or other higher-level languages.

---

Why do I ask about if it should be checked during unit testing? It's because - as far as I know - unit tests shall verify, *if method behaves as it is supposed (documented) to*. In this case it is supposed to accept any of four enum elements and it actually do it, so all tests should pass. Checking for *potential* problems seems to me not to be a concern of the unit testing process. If I'd like to verify all possibilities of *potential* problems in unit tests, I'd probably end up with writing a hundreds of tests for 3-line-of-code methods.

On the other hand it seems like a quite cheap (in terms of spent resources) way of making sure, that the method won't cause any serious problems, when someone decides to add another value to an enum.

Comment: If you add new directions, isn't it likely that you test those, and because you forgot to implement them in the switch/case your code simply does not work? You could simplify the debugging proces by throwing an exception.

Comment: when you say "undefined behavior", this is untrue as far as I can see. The behaviour is well-defined (although possibly unwanted). What do you mean when you say this? Just that you'll fall through the switch without doing anything?

Comment: Imagine, that in C++ someone indexes a statically allocated array with an enum and then just adds an element to that enum. And now try to imagine, how much damage this change can do. In C# the problem may not be as serious as in C++, but still may cause some serious trouble. Heck, this enum can always be casted to int and P/Invoked to a native DLL. Use your imagination, man :) In *this particular case* it won't do much harm, but production code rarely looks like this :)

Comment: @2pietjuh2 Yes, I know that and actually I try to do so every time I do switch through *all* elements of an enum. But either I or anyone else may simply forget about doing so and I'm searching for an automated way of making sure, that this won't happen (or at least will be detected quickly). Actually, I'm kinda hoping of answers, which will help me in resolving any similar [potential] problems.

Comment: Care to comment on a close vote?

Comment: @Spook The close vote is an "off topic" vote.  My comment on that: "odd".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: Yes, I do this routinely.

2: Yes.  I would add this:

```
[ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidArgumentException))]
[Test]
void SomeTestMethod()
{
    Direction testValue = (Direction)-1;
    Assert.IsFalse(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Direction), testValue));
    SomeFunction((Direction)-1);
}
```

Comment: `Assert.IsFalse(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Direction), testValue));` - this is actually quite a bright idea, +1 for this one!

Answer (score 2):

[This problem is actually handled in VS-2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96f5t7fy.aspx). Note that this test is disabled by default.

After enabling the warning you can instruct Vs to treat this particular warning as an error.

Comment: It's good to know that. However, sometimes I might want *on purpose* to do something only if variable matches only a subset of enum's values. (This should be noted explicitly in a comment near the code though)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. That would be ideally to test.
3. I don't know of a tool that can do it.
4. The easiest way is to ALWAYS have a default clause.
      When the default should not do anything write something like:

   ```
   default:
       // No action required
       break;
   ```

   This way you the programmer at least thought about the left over items 
      (if there are any).

Comment: +1 for default with comment, it's wise to inform about it (as well as *intentionally* not verifying all possible values of an enum). However, you provided no automated way of checking, if all programmers follow this path and that's precisely what I'm searching for...